# Nested Loop to help subset data in python

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I have a research dataset which represents scores from participants during multiple visits. I want to see individual scores from each person and each visit. The score categories are "match" or "no match". I tried doing the following but all it gave me was the sum of scores of all visits. How can I tell the code that I want a list of values for every subject and every visit?

and example of the df for one subject looks like this (there are multiple subj and multiple sessions):

```
 subject    Session       Type
    1          1           match
    1          1           match
    1          1           no match
    1          1           match
```

I need to know how many matches per subject, per session. I've tried the following:

```
 subject_ids = df['subject'].unique()

 for subject_id in subject_ids:

   temp_c = df[(df['subject'].isin([subject_id])) 
   total_match = np.size(temp_c, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with what is inside df (df.head(), for example), to make it easier to understand what's inside.

Comment: @sooobus does the updated question help? Thank you!